# Is it possible to mark the C drive read only on an Win 2012 server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I'm wanting to spin up AWS instances where users are allowed to write to an attached D drive, but the C drive containing windows server 2012 will always be fixed, they won't be able to write to it or change it in any way.

So my question(s) are, how can achieve that?

Is this able to be done at the aws level or do I need to create a customised installation of windows that I can use as a template for this?